# How can I inject a new SSL cert and key into a running Node http.Server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket, httpserver, node-https

I am running a secure websocket proxy to a TCP service.  This uses a standard `http.Server` set up like:

```
var webserver = http.createServer(                                                                          
    {                                                                                                       
        key: fs.readFileSync(srv.ssl_key),                                                                  
        cert: fs.readFileSync(srv.ssl_cert),                                                                
    },                                                                                                      
    function(request, response) {                                                                           
        response.writeHead(404);                                                                            
        response.end();                                                                                     
    },                                                                                                      
    function(err) {                                                                                         
        srv.log(err);                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                       
);
```

As you can see, we're already using [hilariously undocumented facilities](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener): the options and error handler arguments to `http.createServer()`.

The SSL key and cert are regenerated periodically by LetsEncrypt certbot.  When this happens, I would like to inject the new key and cert into the webserver without having to regenerate a new one or reinitialize my websocket.

What further undocumented facility will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

1. Close the current webserver with `webserver.close()`
2. Create a new webserver instance with your new key and cert (there's a `.setOptions()` method on it that you might think you could use to change the `key` and `cert` options, but there's no way to get it to generate new TLS credentials after instantiation)
3. Mount the new webserver on the websocket server with `websocketServer.mount(websocketOptions)`, where `websocketOptions.httpServer` is your new webserver instance

This will work nice and smoothly, not interfering with running connections.

Answer (score 1):

## Use SNICallback

Actually, you should not provide `cert` and `key` and instead use [SNICallback](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener) in their place.

(the HTTPS is actually just a wrapper around HTTP and TLS, so it's often better to look directly at the TLS documentation for anything dealing with certificates)

For example:

```
function getCerts(servername, cb) {
  cb(null, tls.createSecureContext({
    key: '...' // privkey.pem
  , cert: '...' // cert.pem + '\\r\\n' + chain.pem
  }));
}

http.createServer({ SNICallback: getCerts });
```

It's important to note that errors are swallowed and result in a browser tls connection error. If you have an error condition I highly recommend that you `console.error(err)` before you `cb(err)` as there is no way to catch it or know what type of error it was. This was an intentional decision by the node team.

## [Greenlock](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock.js) will do this for you

This is exactly what I do with the ssl certificate managers that I wrote, [Greenlock.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock.js) and [Greenlock for Express.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js), which will:

- provision SSL automatically
- dynamically for any domain that you allow
- renew expiring certificates automatically
- hot-load newer certificates
- storage plugin can handle custom logic, as it runs before issuance or renewal

It issues certificates automatically through ACME / Let's Encrypt, however, if you need a more custom solution you could override the default storage plugin to always return a certificate and then it will never even hit the ACME API.